# No suitable driver when trying to create SQL database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to create a new SQL database with this Java program

```
import java.sql.*; //Needed for JDBC classes

public class BuildPhonebookDB {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //Create a named constant for the URL
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:Phonebook;create=true";

    try {
        //Create a connection to the database.
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        //Create a Statement object.
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //Create the Entries table
        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE Entries (" +
                "Name CHAR(20)"+
                "Number INTEGER)"
                );
        System.out.println("Database Connected");
        //Close the connection
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run the program I get an error that:

*No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:Phonebook;create=true*

I have looked at various other similar posts on Stack Overflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255766/no-suitable-driver-found-when-making-sql-connection-to-ms-access-database-in-jav), but none help. I have seen things about a driver jar, but I don't know what this is, if I need to edit this, could someone help me through it?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you remember to add the Derby (or JavaDB) JDBC driver .jar file to your classpath?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this. I am using my textbook as a guide and it doesn't say anything about a .jar file.

Comment: https://db.apache.org/derby/quick_start.html. I guess the writer of your textbook expects you to use a search engine ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you see this [guide](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html) and have you complited all step of this guide?

> **Apache Derby**
>
> Download Derby Download the binary Apache Derby distribution from the
>   Derby web site at http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html.
>   These tutorial instructions use version 10.12.1.1 and assume you
>   downloaded one of the binary distribution files listed in the table
>   below:
>
> Operating System  Download File Windows   db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.zip
>   UNIX, Linux, and Mac  db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz If a more recent
>   release is available, download that, then substitute that version
>   number for 10.12.1.1 in the following instructions.
>
> Install Derby Choose the directory into which you want to install the
>   Derby software. You must have write permissions to this directory. The
>   sample instructions below use C:\Apache for Windows and /opt/Apache
>   for UNIX; be sure to use your actual location. Copy the software
>   distribution to the location you choose, then extract it as shown
>   below.
>
> Windows (use your extraction tool e.g. WinZip -- these instructions
>   use mks unzip):

```
mkdir C:\Apache copy db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.zip
> C:\Apache cd C:\Apache unzip db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.zip
```

> UNIX:

```
mkdir /opt/Apache cp db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz /opt/Apache
> cd /opt/Apache tar xzvf db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz
```

> In both cases, the software will now be extracted into a subdirectory
>   named db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.
>
> Set DERBY_INSTALL Set the DERBY_INSTALL variable to the location where
>   you installed Derby. Examples are shown below, but be sure to use the
>   actual location on your system:
>
> Windows: `C:\> set DERBY_INSTALL=C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin`
>
> UNIX Korn Shell:

```
 $ export
> DERBY_INSTALL=/opt/Apache/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin
```

> Configure Embedded Derby To use Derby in its embedded mode set your
>   CLASSPATH to include the jar files listed below:
>
> derby.jar: contains the Derby engine and the Derby Embedded JDBC
>   driver derbytools.jar: optional, provides the ij tool that is used by
>   a couple of sections in this tutorial You can set your CLASSPATH
>   explicitly with the command shown below:
>
> Windows:

```
C:\> set
> CLASSPATH=%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbytools.jar
```

;.

> UNIX:

```
$ export
> CLASSPATH=$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derbytools.jar:.
```

> ...
>   **Step 3: Embedded Derby**
>
> When an application accesses a Derby database using the Embedded Derby
>   JDBC driver, the Derby engine does not run in a separate process, and
>   there are no separate database processes to start up and shut down.
>   Instead, the Derby database engine runs inside the same Java Virtual
>   Machine (JVM) as the application. So, Derby becomes part of the
>   application just like any other jar file that the application uses.
>   Figure 1 depicts this embedded architecture.
>
> Set the environment
>
> To set up the environment, follow the "[Configure Embedded Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_configure)"
>   instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Use this before you get the connection from the driver:
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();

Comment: I have already tried this, but unfortunately I get a different error: _org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver_